# onItemLongClick works, onItemClick not

Tags: android, expandablelistview, onitemclicklistener

I've got a ExpandableListView which has listeners for both normal and long click, like so:

```
    expandableListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id)
        {
        ...
        }
    });
    expandableListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id)
        {
        ...
        }
    });
```

The weird thing is that the long item click listener is called, but the normal one is not. It does not matter what the long click returns or if the long click is registered at all.

Is there something special for the normal click listener?

Comment: do you return false from your long click listener? To allow the click to propagate

Comment: well, no, I of course turn true, because if the execution has been in the long listener, the event was acted upon.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the OnItemClickListener! That is the whole point of [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

The itemClick is used to expand/collapse a group. You should use `OnChildClickListener`.

However, you can use any combination of [setOnChildClickListener(ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener onChildClickListener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setOnChildClickListener%28android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener%29) and [setOnGroupClickListener(ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener onGroupClickListener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setOnGroupClickListener%28android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener%29)

Comment: Well, I can still register a listener, so it is not weird that I would expect it to work. Especially since the long still works. I had found setOnChildClickListener in the mean time as well. Thanks for responding!